# Ubuntu 17.10 with two NICs: routing requests to correct NIC

Tags: networking, network-manager, ifconfig, nic, netstat

I have done a bunch of searches about this, and found a lot of answers that *don't quite* seem to fit my question. If this question has been answered already, I apologize.

My PC has Ubuntu 17.10, and two NICs. One is connected to one corporate network (we'll call it "A"), and the other to another corporate network (we'll call it "B").

My basic question is, how can requests for the particular resources on Network B all be routed through one NIC, and everything else through Network A and the other NIC?

Each network has cifs or nfs servers which I mount via `/etc/fstab` and each network also has its own domain name servers.

I have Network A set to be the default right now, and I have added a route to Network B. I can `ping` ip addresses on both networks, but I don't seem to be able to use the DNS on Network B.

I had set up Network A with the Network Settings, but I set up the route for Network B in `/etc/network/interfaces` So that's probably causing a conflict of some sort.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's called "Packet Routing". Look at `ip route`. When an IP address is seen, it's compared against the IP/netmask value in a route, and, if it matches, the packet uses that route.

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at `ip route`, and I can see how that will get me most of the way there.
How about the DNS? The DNS on Network A, the default interface, won't have entries for the domain names that live on Network B. Is there a way to say "Use the DNS on Network B to look up `*.foo.corp` or `*.baz.com` and the DNS on Network A for everything else?